# Predicting in Keras with LSTM layer

Tags: python, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to build a text labeling (multilabel) neural network using Keras.

I have built a dictionary of about 2000 words, and encoded training samples as sequeces of word indices of length 140 (with padding).

As the result data looks like a 2D array of `size (num_samples, 140)`. Where number of samples is around 30k.

Here is the definition on my neural network

```
mdl = Sequential()
mdl.add(Embedding((vocab_len + 1), 300, input_length=140))
mdl.add(LSTM(100))

mdl.add(Dense(train_y.shape[1], activation="sigmoid"))

mdl.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=["accuracy"])

history = mdl.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=4, verbose=1, validation_data=(valid_x, valid_y), batch_size=100)
```

During training the Keras shows accuracy around 0.93 on both trainig and validation data. Which looks promising.

But when I try to invoke predict on test data

`pred_y = mdl.predict(test_x, batch_size=100)`

I get an array, where all rows look identical, and all less than 0.5. Hence no labels is set on any of test samples.

[Sample output from mdl.predict()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ip9X.png)

The same behaviour is observed if I run `predict()` on the very same training data I just used to train the model.

But if I run `mdl.evaluate()` I get the same accuracy of 0.93 as shown during model fitting.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Accuracy is not good metrics if your classes are unbalanced. Imaging you have a dataset with 80% of 0's and 20% of 1's. You can create a model which will return 0 in all cases and it's accuracy will be equal to 80%.

Answer (score 0):

`model.predict(test_x, batch_size=100)` will output the probability of each of the classes

`model.predict_classes(test_x, batch_size=100)` will output the most probable class/actual prediction

So from your question it seems you want `model.predict_classes`. Run `dir(model)` to see all available functions.

If you want to generate `model.predict_classes` output from `model.predict` output, do

```
pred = model.predict()
pred_classes_output = pred.argmax(axis=1)
```

what this does is, it goes over every row for example below is output of model.predict which contains probability for class1, class2, class3

[[0.15, 0.73, 0.02], # note the sum of probabilities is = 1

[0.23, 0.33, 0.44]]

it finds the index of the maximum probability i.e 0.73 has index 1, and it creates an array of that so the output will be [1, 2].

`model.evaluate` runs the check on `model.predict_classes`.

Also I hope you understand that if your sample was inherenly biased, say you had 90 of class 1, 10 of class 2, then by just predicting 1 it will get 90% accuracy known as baseline accuracy.